# LocationManager in 2.1 not working?

Tags: android, android-location, locationmanager, android-gps

I have been trying to get the following code to work for the last 4 hours.

```
public void clearLocation() { 
    LocationManager locMan =
            (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
    locMan.clearTestProviderLocation("gps");
```

My problem is that it will only work with Android 1.5. On 1.6 and newer it just crashes when it reaches the second statement.

I've been looking through various code snippets and tutorials, but haven't been able to find anything about this.

Regards, Adam.

Comment: Use 'adb logcat', DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to see your Java stack trace, which should tell you what your error is.

Comment: Well i did.. it gives me an invalid argument of some kind..
so i guess they changed something in the android code from 1.6 and upwards.. but i can't figure out how to do it any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... found out that you can't change anything about the location provider "gps" in 1.6+

Comment: Considering that doing so would be a security violation -- allowing you to forge being GPS -- I'm not terribly surprised.